# foreignKey doesn't appear

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Hy,
I've made 3 sequelize/mysql models : User, Post and Comment. I've implemented OneToMany relatioship betwen both User/Post and Post/Comment. But when refreshing phpMyAdmin the foreign keys didn't appear. Though they are supposed to be generated automatically. What's wrong with my code?

User.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        //required: true
    },
    firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        //required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        //required: true,
        unique: {
            msg: "email already taken. Please choose another one!"
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        //required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
        default: "BASIC"
    }
});
return User;
```

}

Post.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    message: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        trim: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    pictureURL: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    videoURL: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    likers: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        get() {
            return this.getDataValue('likers').split(';')
        },
        set(val) {
            this.setDataValue('likers', val.join(';'));
        },
    },
    dislikers: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        get() {
            return this.getDataValue('dislikers').split(';')
        },
        set(val) {
            this.setDataValue('dislikers', val.join(';'));
        },
    },
    
    likes: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        default: 0
    },
    dislikes: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        default: 0
    },
});
return Post;
```

}

Comment.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    message: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        trim: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    pictureURL: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    videoURL: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    likers: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        get() {
            return this.getDataValue('likers').split(';')
        },
        set(val) {
            this.setDataValue('likers', val.join(';'));
        },
    },
    dislikers: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        get() {
            return this.getDataValue('dislikers').split(';')
        },
        set(val) {
            this.setDataValue('dislikers', val.join(';'));
        },
    },

    likes: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        default: 0
    },
    dislikes: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        default: 0
    },
});
return Comment;
```

}

relations.js

```
    const { User } = require("../models/User");
const { Post } = require("../models/Post");
const { Comment } = require("../models/Comment");

Post.hasMany(Comment, {
    foreignKey: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
Comment.belongsTo(Post);

User.hasMany(Post, {
    foreignKey: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
Post.belongsTo(User);
```

Comment: where you want to add foreign key constraints, can you tell me the columns name

Comment: normally we need fk in post table and comment table. I thought sequelize add them automatically but it seems not!